Why is this bringing back a filled array?
I am trying to find out what venues are opened at present using a filter, the thing works well when the time is in between and after the time is not. Then come late night and everything changes.
I am using Moment JS to compare the time now Hour to the close and open in an object.
The object has this format
value = [ {
  "id" : "place_01",
    "name" : "Place One",
    "location" : "Location One",
    "hours" : [
    {"day": "Sunday", "day_id": 0,
    "hours": "9:00 AM - 5:00 PM", "open": "9:00 AM", "close": "5:00 PM", "tags": "" },
    {"day": "Monday", "day_id": 1,
    "hours": "9:00 AM - 5:00 PM", "open": "9:00 AM", "close": "5:00 PM", "tags": "" },
    {"day": "Tuesday", "day_id": 2,
    "hours": "9:00 AM - 5:00 PM", "open": "9:00 AM", "close": "5:00 PM", "tags": "" },
    {"day": "Wednesday", "day_id": 3,
    "hours": "9:00 AM - 5:00 PM", "open": "9:00 AM", "close": "5:00 PM", "tags": ""  },
    {"day": "Thursday", "day_id": 4,
    "hours": "9:00 AM - 5:00 PM", "open": "9:00 AM", "close": "5:00 PM", "tags": "" },
    {"day": "Friday", "day_id": 5,
    "hours": "9:00 AM - 9:00 PM", "open": "9:00 AM", "close": "9:00 PM", "tags": "" },
    {"day": "Saturday", "day_id": 6,
    "hours": "9:00 AM - 9:00 PM", "open": "9:00 AM", "close": "9:00 PM", "tags": "" }
    ]
    }
]

This is the filter
 let f1 =  value.filter(item => item.hours.some((hour: { day_id: any; close: string; open: string; }) => hour.day_id == moment().format('d') && hour.open <= moment().format('LT') && hour.close >= moment().format('LT') ));

I wanted the filter to bring back value only when all variables are true.
i.e. If the day ID is # and the close if more than Moment() etc...
When the time is between both everything is great then for a few hours after it works fine, where it won't bring back any values, then at nigh it starts bring values back, very weird.
How can I get this to only bring back values when the time it between xyz times on xyz day.

I think the problem is comparing strings, "9:00 PM" > "8:00 PM" but "9:00 PM" > "11:00 PM". Right?

something like that. The comparison works for a specific amount of time after close time where the array f1 comes back empty, then at say 11PM it starts bring back  items again

Should i convert to 24 hours and get only the hour back ?

You may have a better result, especially if you also use leading zeros, 09:00 instead of 9:00. But it sounds like the better approach would be to convert to numbers, for example, "9:00 AM" to 540 and "9:00 PM" to 1260 (it's in minutes, in case something closes at 9:30). Comparing numbers doesn't cause such issues because they are numbers.

Yes. I am working on that as I type.
